# Is it possible to have page breaks report in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to create a report with page breaks in SSRS (For example create 6 pages of A4 size report?

Comment: Yes (15 characters).

Comment: [Add a Page Break (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-page-break-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can add a page break while designing reports.**

Based on the following official documentation:

- [Add a Page Break (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-page-break-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

> You can add a page break to rectangles, data regions, or groups within data regions to control the amount of information on each page. Adding page breaks can improve the performance of published reports because only the items on each page have to be processed as you view the report. When the whole report is a single page, all items must be processed before you can view the report.

Also, the link above contains a guide on how to:

- To add a page break to a data region
- To add a page break to a rectangle
- To add a page break to a row group in a table, matrix, or list

**Other helpful articles**

- [Insert Page Breaks in SSRS Report](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/insert-page-breaks-in-ssrs-report/)
- [Pagination in Reporting Services (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/pagination-in-reporting-services-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)
- [How to add Page Breaks in SSRS( SQL Server Reporting Services)](http://burnignorance.com/reporting-tools-tips/how-to-add-page-breaks-in-ssrs-sql-server-reporting-services/)